# CMake Errors when installing OpenCV 4.1.2 with OpenCV contrib 4.1.2

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

I installed both OpenCV and OpenCV contrib 4.1.2 from their github and their website for usage of their dnn module in Visual Studio. I have been having trouble getting CMake to configure and generate whatever is necessary.

Here's the error I'm smacked with:

```
Detected processor: AMD64
libjpeg-turbo: VERSION = 2.0.2, BUILD = opencv-4.1.2-libjpeg-turbo
IPPICV: Download: ippicv_2019_win_intel64_20180723_general.zip
found Intel IPP (ICV version): 2019.0.0 [2019.0.0 Gold]
at: C:/opencv+contrib/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_win/icv
found Intel IPP Integration Wrappers sources: 2019.0.0
at: C:/opencv+contrib/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_win/iw
Could not find OpenBLAS include. Turning OpenBLAS_FOUND off
Could not find OpenBLAS lib. Turning OpenBLAS_FOUND off
Could NOT find BLAS (missing: BLAS_LIBRARIES) 
LAPACK requires BLAS
A library with LAPACK API not found. Please specify library location.
VTK is not found. Please set -DVTK_DIR in CMake to VTK build directory, or to VTK install subdirectory with VTKConfig.cmake file
CMake Error at cmake/OpenCVModule.cmake:289 (message):
  No modules has been found: C:/opencv_contrib-4.1.2
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/OpenCVModule.cmake:371 (_glob_locations)
  modules/CMakeLists.txt:7 (ocv_glob_modules)


ADE: Download: v0.1.1f.zip
OpenCV Python: during development append to PYTHONPATH: C:/opencv+contrib/python_loader
FFMPEG: Download: opencv_videoio_ffmpeg.dll
FFMPEG: Download: opencv_videoio_ffmpeg_64.dll
FFMPEG: Download: ffmpeg_version.cmake
Registering hook 'INIT_MODULE_SOURCES_opencv_dnn': C:/opencv/opencv/sources/modules/dnn/cmake/hooks/INIT_MODULE_SOURCES_opencv_dnn.cmake
opencv_dnn: filter out cuda4dnn source code
CMake Warning at cmake/OpenCVGenSetupVars.cmake:54 (message):
  CONFIGURATION IS NOT SUPPORTED: validate setupvars script in install
  directory
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:944 (include)
```

Another post I found when googling said that maybe the Python path isn't correct, but when I enter `python --version` in cmd it tells me Python 3.7.4

Comment: Do you need the extra modules in contrib? I build opencv 4.1.2 a few weeks ago, and when I build with the extra modules I also had allot of issues. I build it without the extra modules, and I'm not facing any issues at this moment

Comment: For which language do you try to build OpenCV?

Comment: Yeah I need the dnn module and it threw like 100+ compilation errors without the contrib.

Comment: I'm trying to build it for C++

Comment: Have you tried to install openCV via [vcpkg](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg). I have installed it via vcpkg, but I'm not sure if the extra modules are build there.

Comment: I never heard of this, I'll have to check it out. Do you know if it allows access of the dnn module?

Answer (score 0):

Try to install [vcpkg](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg), from here you can both download and install OpenCV x86 and x64. However, not all modules are available here. The most common ones are available including DNN, see image below.
[image]

To install OpenCV with the DNN package, you will need to enter the following line:

- X86: `.\vcpkg install opencv4[dnn]`
- X64: `.\vcpkg install opencv4[dnn]:x64-windows`

Comment: While this did take away the errors with including, ie ``#include <opencv2\dnn.hpp>``, this did not fix my import completely it seems. I did ``.\vcpkg opencv4[dnn]:x64-windows`` and it is there when I ``./vcpkg list`` but the line in my code that says ``cv::dnn::Net net;`` still throws an error and says there there is no ``Net`` in ``cv::dnn`` and then throws compilation errors saying that ``Error C3646 'CV_NOEXCEPT': unknown override specifier (compiling source file src\main.cpp)`` and other errors